# JavaScript Templating: How should the partial template code be organized?

Tags: javascript, templates, javascript-framework, template-engine

I am new to the world of JavaScript Templating.

Here I have a page, in which I don't know how the template code should be organized.

This is the relevant HTML When the page is first loaded:

```
...
<table id="color-codes">
  <tr>
    <td>red</td>
    <td>#FF0000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>blue</td>
    <td>#0000FF</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>black</td>
    <td>#000000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
...
```

The user can add colors to the table. Each time a color is added, the browser dispatchs an AJAX request to the server. The server then returns a JSON object that has both the color name and the color code.

Upon receiving the JSON object, the client-end renders the template (below) with the JSON object and then insert the resultant DOM object into the end of the table.

The table-row template:

```
<tr id='tp-color-entry'>
  <td class='color-name'></td>
  <td class='color-code'></td>
</tr>
```

Question: Where should I place this template code? In HTML file? Or JS file? If in HTML file, how to prevent it to interfere with the page presentation/layout? If in JS file, do I just save assign it to a variable?

Note that I use **[Pure](http://beebole.com/pure/)** for JS Templating and Django as my server-end. And I always try to keep HTML and JS code into separate files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it in a `script` tag with an unrecognized `type` attribute:

```
<script type="text/x-pure-template" id="color-entry-template">
    <tr id='tp-color-entry'>
        <td class='color-name'></td>
        <td class='color-code'></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Then it's a simple matter to retrieve the template:

```
document.getElementById('color-entry-template').textContent
```

Comment: Ah~ that explains why I saw some people put their template code in a script tag with `text/html` type (browser doesn't know how to execute a text/html script). Thank you, mate.